# Effective message dispatching

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code, that works fine. However, I know there is a lot of code duplication and C-style programming. In the code example there only is a `DeviceOneDispatcher`, in reality there are more child classes and case options.

The question is how to optimize/refactor this code best following c++11-c++17. 
I believe a big part of the duplication, could be solved by using a template. But I am not sure how implement this.

````
class BaseDispatcher
{
public:
    BaseDispatcher()          = default;
    virtual ~BaseDispatcher() = default;

    result_t Init(uint8_t idx)
    {
        msgHandler.Init(idx);
    };

    void Execute(MainControl &ctrl)
    {
        MsgInfo msg = { 0 };
        if (msgHandler.RxMsg(msg))
        {
        switch (msg.msgID)
        {
            case REQ_PING:
                HandlePing(msg);
                break;
            case REQ_VERSION:
                HandleVersion(msg);
                break;
            default:
                SpecificExecute(msg, ctrl);
        }
    };

protected:
    void HandlePing(const MsgInfo &msg)
    {
        txMsg = msgHandler.ReserveMsg(msg.msgID, sizeof(DefaultMsg_t));

        if (nullptr != txMsg.msgBuf)
        {
            auto *response = (DefaultMsg_t *)txMsg.msgBuf;
            response->ack = htons(static_cast<uint16_t>(Reply::ACCEPTED));
            msgHandler.SendMsg(txMsg);
            mainCtrl->GetConsole().OutputEnable();
        }
    };
    void HandleVersion(const MsgInfo &msg)
    {
        txMsg = msgHandler.ReserveMsg(msg.msgID, sizeof(VersionInfoMsg_t));

        if (nullptr != txMsg.msgBuf)
        {
            auto *response = (VersionInfoMsg_t *)txMsg.msgBuf;
            memset(response->name, 0, 32);
            response->svnRevision  = htons(svnRevision);
            uint8_t sl = (uint8_t)strlen(sw);
            memcpy(response->name, sw, sl <= 32 ? sl : 32);
            msgHandler.SendMsg(txMsg);
        }
    };
    void HandleUnknown(const MsgInfo &msg)
    {
        txMsg = msgHandler.ReserveMsg(msg.msgID, sizeof(DefaultMsg_t));

        if (nullptr != txMsg.msgBuf)
        {
            auto *response = (DefaultMsg_t *)txMsg.msgBuf;
            response->ack = htons(static_cast<uint16_t>(Reply::UNKNOWN_REQ));
            msgHandler.SendMsg(txMsg);
        }
    };
    virtual void SpecificExecute(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl);

    MsgHandler &GetMsgHandler() { return msgHandler; }

protected:
    MsgInfo         txMsg;
    MsgHandler      msgHandler;
    static const char* sw = "Embedded Test Program";
};


class DeviceOneDispatcher : public BaseDispatcher
{
    public:
        DeviceOneDispatcher ()          = default;
        virtual ~DeviceOneDispatcher () = default;

    void SpecificExecute(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl) override
    {
        switch (msg.msgID)
        {
            case INFO_TEMP:
                HandleTemperature(msg, ctrl);
                break;
            default:
                HandleUnknown(msg);
        }
    };

    protected:
        void HandleTemperature(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl)
        {
            float temperature = (float)ntohl(*(uint16_t*)msg.msgBuf) / 10;
            ctrl.GetRFMonitor().SetTemperature(temperature);
        };
};

class DeviceTwoDispatcher : public BaseDispatcher
{
    public:
        DeviceTwoDispatcher ()          = default;
        virtual ~DeviceTwoDispatcher () = default;

    void SpecificExecute(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl) override
    {
        switch (msg.msgID)
        {
            case INFO_TEMP:
                HandleMotor(msg, ctrl);
                break;
            default:
                HandleUnknown(msg);
        }
    };

    protected:
        void HandleMotor(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl)
        {
            //do something
        };
};
Class MainController()
{
    public:
        Execute()
        {
            dispatcherOne.Execute(*this);
            dispatcherTwo.Execute(*this);
        }
        DeviceOneDispatcher   &GetDispatcherOne() { return dispatcherOne; }
        DeviceTwoDispatcher   &GetDispatcherTwo() { return dispatcherTwo; }
    protected:
        DeviceOneDispatcher   dispatcherOne;
        DeviceTwoDispatcher   dispatcherTwo;
}
```
````

Comment: This code seems to be incomplete, there is no function HandleConsoleVerbosity()

Comment: This code can't compile, the function `HandleVersion()` uses the variable sw which is never defined. Suggestion turn all of your C style casts into static casts.

Comment: The code does compile, however as this is only a snapshot of the program not everything is defined here.

Comment: @RForce Please include the rest as well to avoid such confusion. We need to see code in it's context, otherwise a review would be filled with guesswork. That helps nobody.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you just need a dispatcher and some msghanlders., not many dispatchers.
the codes can modify like this:

```
class BaseDispatcher
{
public:
    BaseDispatcher()          = default;
    virtual ~BaseDispatcher() = default;

    result_t Init(uint8_t idx)
    {
        //msgHandler.Init(idx);
        //to init pmsgHandlerVec
    };

    void Execute(MainControl &ctrl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pmsgHandlerVec.size(); ++i)
        {
            BaseHandler* phandler = pmsgHandlerVec[i];
            bool res = phandler->handle_msg(txMsg, ctrl);
            if (res)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    };

protected:
    MsgInfo         txMsg;
    std::vector<BaseHandler*>      pmsgHandlerVec;
    static const char* sw = "Embedded Test Program";
};

class BaseHandler
{
    public:
        virtual bol handle_msg(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl) = 0;
}

class Handler1 : public BaseHandler
{
    public:
        virtual bool handle_msg(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl)
        {
            switch (msg.msgID)
            {
            case REQ_PING:
                HandlePing(msg);
                break;
            case REQ_VERSION:
                HandleVersion(msg);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}

class Handler2 : public BaseHandler
{
    public:
        virtual bool handle_msg(const MsgInfo &msg, MainControl &ctrl)
        {
            switch (msg.msgID)
            {
            case INFO_TEMP:
                HandleTemperature(msg, ctrl);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
} 

Class MainController()
{
    public:
        Execute()
        {
            dispatcher.Execute(*this);
        }
    protected:
        BaseDispatcher   dispatcher;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is the best solution in this case. I would like to know which handle I am using. For example ```DeviceOneDispatcher.Execute()```. With a vector you dont know this. Besides I need to be able to use the device handle from other classes declared in ```MainControl``` as well.  The switch case from Handler1 should be common for all the devices handlers and supplemented with the specific switch cases per device. I edited my code example for more clerification

Comment: (Welcome to *finally* posting on stack exchange!)